# windows 2003 server : does failed FRSEvent prevent xp client from joining domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-replication-services

i recently ran DCDiag.exe and one of the errors was

`failed test frsevent and failed test kccevent`

would this prevent a Windows XP prof client computer from joining a domain?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact error it could. Specifically the kccevent. I can't think of a FRS error that would cause it, but it would cause your clients to get incorrect/outdated policies and scripts once joined. KCC is related to authentication so it's possible.